# The fast way to compere Array with different objects type

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, core-data, mkmapview

I have a one array with fetch results from coredata and it's contain object `myObject` with property `myObjId`.

And i have `MKAnnotation`on my `MapView`, so I have an array with custom annotation with `Id`:

`self.mapView.annotations` return object `CustomPinAnnotation` with `myId` property.

What i want to do is sync this two results without reloading existing pins on the map. How to find data in `annotations` array which is NOT in the results array from CoreData?

I wrote that method to check right before annotation will be added:

```
-(BOOL)isAlreadyDisplayOnMap:(NSNumber*)pinId {
    for(CustomPinAnnotation *an in self.mapView.annotations) {
        if(![an isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
            if([an.favourId integerValue] == [pinId integerValue]) {
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

But this is terribly slow and should be a better way to compare arrays.

Comment: for in loop is fastest loop which iterate in forward direction

Comment: Note that you don't have to rely on the map view's `annotations` array to know what annotations are on the map.  You can always keep your _own_ "list" of annotations on the map but in a structure that supports _immediate_ querying by pinId (like an NSDictionary with the key as the pinId).

Comment: Completely unrelated but in the existing code, I'd suggest changing the `if` condition to check if the object **is** the class you're looking for (`CustomPinAnnotation`) instead of checking if it's **not** `MKUserLocation`.  This way, you can be more sure that the custom property access will not fail and will account for the possibility that there might be more than just the two class types.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try using block:

```
     __block BOOL alreadyDisplayed;
    [self.mapView.annotations enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
       CustomPinAnnotation *an = (CustomPinAnnotation *)obj;
          if(![an isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
             if([an.favourId integerValue] == [pinId integerValue]) {
                alreadyDisplayed = YES;
                *stop = YES;
             }
          }
    }];
```